# MapBox RMMapView Origin Offsets When Orientation Changes

Tags: ios7, maps, mapkit, screen-orientation, mapbox

In my Tabbed Application, I added subview of type MapBox RMMapView to my main view.

My problem is the map center gets thrown off when I change orientation. The map view adjust to the orientation but the center of the map does not. Please provide suggestions to fix it? Thank you for your time.

** I tried both setAutoresizingMask but it has no effect.

[self.view setAutoresizingMask:
   (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight)];

[self.mapView setAutoresizingMask:
   (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight)];

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why this is the case, but I would recommend that you not add or manipulate subviews within the `RMMapView`, but instead add one over top.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I took out the the subview as you recommended but it did not fix the problem. It seems like the map view image rotates and extends to bounds but the touchable area does not. The touchable area stays in the vertical orientation position and does not extend to the horizontal bounds. Any suggestions here?

Comment: If I double touch the area that's not responding, the map will zoom in. However, it still doesn't respond to swipe gestures.

Comment: Ah, ok, I think I follow. The swipe layer (`RMMapOverlayView` in the internals of the SDK, which is open source) may not be adopting the superview's constraints for resizing. I will check this out and report back.

Comment: I'm not seeing any problems in my own testing. You might try editing `RMMapOverlayView` to add a `backgroundColor` of something noticeable, but translucent. Then you can see the coverage when rotating. Maybe there is something specific to your setup.

Comment: I'm going to rebuild my app so I may where and when I have the issue. I'll report back when I've isolated the problem.

Comment: Do you think it could have something to do with the fact that I'm using a Tabbed Application? Perhaps the RMMapView is not compatible with a Tabbed Application. Whenever you change orientation the swipe layer gets out of sync with map view.

Comment: If the app starts in portrait, the center of the map is in the center of the map view. When the orientation changes to landscape, the center of the map is in the bottom lefthand side of the map view. The swipe layer is centered around center of the map, so it's shifted towards the center leaving the righthand side inaccessible. The same but opposite occurs if you start in landscape and switch to the portrait. I guess the real question is, How do I ensure the center of the map stays in the center of the map view during orientation changes?

Comment: I was hoping [_mapView setAutoresizingMask:
   (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight)]; would fix it but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to solve this by defining the view.frame for each orientation.

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration 

{
if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
  toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
{

CGRect frame = CGRectMake(x, y, x, y);

_mapView.frame = frame;

_mapView.userTrackingMode = RMUserTrackingModeFollow;

} else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {

CGRect frame = CGRectMake(x, y, x, y);

_mapView.frame = frame;

_mapView.userTrackingMode = RMUserTrackingModeFollow;

}
}
```